# Change of the last element of the string PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone help me with a function that changes the last digit of the number to `x`.

`123456789` -> `12345678x`

I tried to do:

```
$var = 123456789; 
$w = str_replace(substr( $var, -1), "x", $var);
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $var = 123456789;
  $w = str_replace(substr( $var, -1), "x", $var);

Comment: but only to the last just the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by accessing the last element of the string through `$string[-1]` and setting it to your desired value. This will overwrite the last character in the string.

```
$string = "123456789";
$string[-1] = "x";
echo $string;
```

See [this live demo](https://3v4l.org/25Nu5).

Comment: And whether it can be done for the board, because I download a lot of numbers from the database and I would like it to work for everyone

Comment: It will work for any string, replacing the last value to `x`.

Comment: So I have to loop the array, change the value to a string and then use it?

Comment: I have done a good job, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with following code

```
$x = 123456789;
echo ((int)($x / 10) . 'x');
```